# How to export values to TXT file in STM32CubeIDE

Tags: stm32, embedded, stm32cubemx, putty

I have a code for ADC: (STM32F407)

```c
#include "stm32f4xx.h"
#include "stdio.h"

extern void initialise_monitor_handles(void);

unsigned int value;
float stepSize=0.01171875;
float voltage;
int x=0;

void TIM2_Configuration(void)
{
    // enable TIM2 clock (bit0)
    RCC->APB1ENR |= (1 << 0);

    TIM2->PSC = 16000-1;
    TIM2->ARR = 100; //

    /* Reset the MMS Bits */
    TIM2->CR2 &= (uint16_t)~TIM_CR2_MMS;
    /* Select the TRGO source */
    TIM2->CR2 |=  TIM_CR2_MMS_1; //UPDATE EVENT

    // Enable Timer 2 module (CEN, bit0)
    TIM2->CR1 |= (1 << 0);
}

void init_ADC(void)
{
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOCEN; //GPIOC clock enable
    GPIOC->MODER |= (3u<<(2*0));  //ADC input pin is analog mode, PC0
    RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_ADC1EN; //ADC clock enable
    RCC->CFGR |= 7<<13; //APB2ENR has 16/16 = 1Mhz
    ADC->CCR |= (3<<16); //1MHz/8 = 125kHz.

    ADC1->SQR1 &= ~ADC_SQR1_L; //set number of conversions per sequence to 1
    ADC1->SQR3 &= ~ADC_SQR3_SQ1; //clear channel select bits
    ADC1->SQR3 |= 10; //set channel
    ADC1->CR1 &= ~ADC_CR1_SCAN; //SCAN mode disabled
    ADC1->CR1 |= 1<<25; //set 8 bit
    ADC1->CR2 &= ~ADC_CR2_CONT; //continuous conversion

    ADC1->CR2 &=  ~(1<<29);
    ADC1->CR2 |= (1<<28); //Trigger on Rising edge

    //External Event TIM2 TRGO
    ADC1->CR2 |= 1<<25 | 1<<26;

    ADC1->SMPR2 |= 7<<0; //488 cycles
    //Sampling frequency = 125k/(480+8) = 256.147Hz
    //For 50 Hz sine wave.

    ADC1->CR2 |= ADC_CR2_ADON; //enable ADC
    ADC1->CR2 |= ADC_CR2_SWSTART;
}

void msDelay(int msTime)
{
    //Assume for loop take 12 clock cycles and system clock is 16MHz
    int Time = msTime * 1333;
    for(int i = 0; i < Time; i++);
}

int main()
{
    //FPU enable
    //Co-processor (core peripheral) access control register
    SCB->CPACR |= (0xF<<20);
    TIM2_Configuration();
    init_ADC();
    msDelay(500);
    x++;
    initialise_monitor_handles();
    while(1)
    {
        while (!(ADC1->SR & (1<<1))) {
            __NOP();
        }

        value = ADC1->DR;
        voltage = stepSize * value;
        printf("%f", voltage);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

It's working fine. I am able to print the voltage values onto terminal as well.
How do I export these values into a txt file? I mean, apart from copy-pasting, because my end goal is to do this in real time.

What I found is we have to use software like PuTTY or Teraterm. But that requires a UART connection via on-board USB cable. Is that possible via on board USB? Or is there some other way?

Comment: You could write some python to do this for you.

Comment: Teraterm can log to a file iirc.

Comment: What is your board?